# How to display markers from sqlite on OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, sqlite, openstreetmap, markers

I'm creating application with Sqlite Database and OpenStreetMap. In my db I've store some data like id, type of building, year, function, latitude and longitude. I'm trying display on OpenStreetMap markers from db and one marker with current GPS position.
At this moment at my map is displaying my location and first record from db.
How can I display all markers on map?
P.S. I tried to do it using various examples found in Google

My Mapa class

```
public class Mapa extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private MapView osm;
private MapController mc;
private LocationManager locationManager;
WywiadData WywiadData;
int id_marker;
Double Dlugosc;
Double Szerokosc;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final int newScale = (int) (256 * scale);
    String[] OSMSource = new String[2];
    OSMSource[0] = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/";
    OSMSource[1] = "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/";
    XYTileSource MapSource = new XYTileSource("OSM", null, 1, 18, newScale, ".png", OSMSource);
    osm.setTileSource(MapSource);
    osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    osm.setMaxZoomLevel(18);
    osm.setMinZoomLevel(1);
    mc = (MapController) osm.getController();
    mc.setZoom(18);
    GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(50.2586, 19.0223);
    mc.animateTo(center);
    WywiadData = new WywiadData(this, null, null, 1);
    Cursor cursor = WywiadData.getMarkers();
    Double Dlq = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Dlugosc"));
    Double Szr = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Szerokosc"));
    id_marker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    Dlugosc = Double.valueOf(Dlq);
    Szerokosc = Double.valueOf(Szr);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void addMarker(GeoPoint center) {
    Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
    marker.setPosition(center);
    Marker marker2 = new Marker(osm);
    marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    GeoPoint center2 = new GeoPoint(Dlugosc, Szerokosc);
    marker2.setPosition(center2);
    marker2.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    osm.getOverlays().add(marker);
    osm.getOverlays().add(marker2);
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mc.animateTo(center);
    osm.getOverlays().clear();
    addMarker(center);
    osm.invalidate();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

And my Db class:

```
public class WywiadData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "WYWIAD.db";
public static final int DATA_BASE_VERSION = 1;
public final static String TAG = "Wywiad Data";

public WywiadData(Context context, Object o, Object o1, int i) {
    super(context, DATA_BASE_NAME, null, DATA_BASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + Tabela._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Tabela.OPERATOR + " TEXT, " + Tabela.FUNKCJA + " TEXT, " + Tabela.KOD_FUNKCJI + " TEXT, " + Tabela.MATERIAL + " TEXT, " + Tabela.ROK + " INTEGER, " + Tabela.ZRODLO + " TEXT, " + Tabela.KOND_NADZ + " INTEGER, " + Tabela.KOND_PODZ + " INTEGER, " + Tabela.STATUS + " TEXT, " + Tabela.DLUGOSC + " TEXT, " + Tabela.SZEROKOSC + " TEXT, " + Tabela.DATA + " TEXT, " + Tabela.UWAGI + " TEXT" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Operator, String Funkcja, String Kod, String Material, String Rok, String Zrodlo, String Kond_nadz, String Kond_podz, String Status, String DataDodania, Double Dlugosc, Double Szerkosc, String Uwagi) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Tabela.OPERATOR, Operator);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.FUNKCJA, Funkcja);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOD_FUNKCJI, Kod);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.MATERIAL, Material);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.ROK, Rok);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.ZRODLO, Zrodlo);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOND_NADZ, Kond_nadz);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOND_PODZ, Kond_podz);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.STATUS, Status);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.DATA, DataDodania);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.DLUGOSC, Dlugosc);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.SZEROKOSC, Szerkosc);
    contentValues.put(Tabela.UWAGI, Uwagi);
    long result = db.insert(Tabela.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getListContents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}


public Cursor getItemID(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = " SELECT * FROM " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Tabela._ID + " = '" + id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    }
    Log.e("Wywiad", "zwrócono po id: " + cursor);
    return cursor;
}


public void updateData(Lista lista) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Tabela.OPERATOR, lista.getOperator());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.FUNKCJA, lista.getfunkcja());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOD_FUNKCJI, lista.getKod());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.MATERIAL, lista.getmaterial());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.ROK, lista.getrok());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.ZRODLO, lista.getzrodlo());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOND_NADZ, lista.getKondygnacje_nad());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.KOND_PODZ, lista.getKondygnacje_pod());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.STATUS, lista.getstatus());
    contentValues.put(Tabela.UWAGI, lista.getuwagi());
    db.update(Tabela.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, Tabela._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(lista.getIdentyfikator())});
    db.close();

}

public void deleteData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = " DELETE FROM " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Tabela._ID + " = '" + id + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public Cursor getMarkers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + Tabela.TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    }
    return cursor;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually create a Marker, what you want to do is define the characteristics of the Marker using MarkerOptions and then add it to the Map

```
public void addMarker(GeoPoint center) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
    options.position(center);
    options.anchor( Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);

    Marker marker = osm.AddMarker(options);
}
```

**EDIT**
to add all from sqlite

```
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(cursor.getLong("lat"), cursor.getLong("lng"));
        addMarker(point);
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

this will iterate through all of the objects in the cursor, create a GeoPoint and then pass it to the addMarker method

Comment: So how can I display all markers from sqlite? Could You explain it to me? I'm so sorry, I'm just starting programing and it's too difficult for me at this moment.